# $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f(n)=0 \Longrightarrow f'(n)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real function such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f(n)=0$

I would like to know if is it true that
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f'(n)=0
$$

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is definitely not always true. Consider the function
$$f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$$
This function is equal to $0$ for all integer $x$, but
$$f'(x)=\pi \cos(\pi x)$$
Which is obviously not.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: @MateyMath No problem! And nice username!

Comment: a friend of mine teases me about my username so thanks